# Vuejs performance issue

Tags: vue.js

I've a sms dashboard application in vuejs. When I'm loading 100 users' data in each page, it's getting too slow to load. It's taking about one minute. After debugging I've found the header and footer part when loading, then the application becomes slow. As header and footer have many features. But how can I resolve this?

I tried to use v-if, or v-show where ever required, used computed property somewhere but no improvement. I'm giving the header code here,

```html
<h1 class="heading">
  <div class="button-set">
    <div
      v-if="item.addedTags && item.addedTags.length > 0"
      class="added-tags"
    >
      <el-tag
        v-for="tag in item.addedTags"
        :key="tag.label_id"
        closable
        :type="tag.label_type"
        size="small"
        round
        style="font-size: 0.6rem; margin-left: 5px; height: 18px"
        @close="mfToRemoveTags(item.phoneNumber, tag.label_id)"
        >{{ tag.label_name }}</el-tag
      >
    </div>

    <el-popover placement="bottom-end" :width="150" trigger="click">
      <template #reference>
        <el-button type="" circle :icon="MoreFilled" size="small"></el-button>
      </template>
      <div class="prompt-header-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <el-button
              v-if="item.assignToUser && item.assignToUser.isPinned"
              type="danger"
              :icon="CloseBold"
              size="small"
              link
              @click="mfToRemovePinFromThisChat(item.phoneNumber)"
              >Unpin chat</el-button
            >
            <el-button
              v-else
              type="primary"
              link
              :icon="Paperclip"
              size="small"
              @click="mfToPinThisChat(item.phoneNumber)"
              >Pin chat</el-button
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <el-popconfirm
              confirm-button-text="Yes"
              cancel-button-text="No"
              :icon="InfoFilled"
              icon-color="#626AEF"
              title="Are you sure to clear the message?"
              width="250"
              @confirm="mfToMoveToRecycleBin(item.phoneNumber)"
            >
              <template #reference>
                <el-button type="danger" link :icon="Delete" size="small"
                  >Move to Recycle bin</el-button
                >
              </template>
            </el-popconfirm>
          </li>
          <li>
            <el-switch
              v-model="item.therapistTakeOver"
              size="small"
              style="--el-switch-on-color: #409eff"
              active-text="Human take over"
              inactive-text="LLM take over"
              inline-prompt
              @change="mfTherapistTakeOver(item)"
            />
          </li>
          <li>
            <el-button
              type="primary"
              link
              :icon="UserFilled"
              size="small"
              @click="mfToOpenAssignToFormDialog(item)"
              >Assign to user</el-button
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <el-button
              type="primary"
              link
              :icon="CollectionTag"
              size="small"
              @click="mfToOpenAddTagsFormDialog(item)"
              >Add tags</el-button
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <el-popover placement="bottom" :width="185" trigger="click">
              <template #reference>
                <el-button
                  type="primary"
                  link
                  :icon="Flag"
                  size="small"
                  @click="
                    item.assignToUser
                      ? (priority = item.assignToUser.priority)
                      : (priority = 1)
                  "
                  >Assign priority</el-button
                >
              </template>
              <div class="prompt-priority">
                <el-form class="prompt-priority-form">
                  <el-form-item style="margin-bottom: 5px">
                    <el-radio-group v-model="priority" size="small">
                      <el-radio-button :label="1">Low</el-radio-button>
                      <el-radio-button :label="2">Medium</el-radio-button>
                      <el-radio-button :label="3">High</el-radio-button>
                    </el-radio-group>
                  </el-form-item>
                  <el-form-item class="button_wrap" style="margin-bottom: 0">
                    <el-button
                      type="primary"
                      size="small"
                      @click="mfToSetPriority(item.phoneNumber, priority)"
                      >Save</el-button
                    >
                  </el-form-item>
                </el-form>
              </div>
            </el-popover>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </el-popover>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 0; display: flex">
    <div style="flex: 1.5; padding: 2px 0 2px 5px">
      <div>
        <span v-if="registeredUserList[item.phoneNumber.slice(-10)]">
          <el-link
            :underline="false"
            :href="
              registeredUserList[item.phoneNumber.slice(-10)].publicUniqueId
                ? patientChartBaseUrl +
                  registeredUserList[item.phoneNumber.slice(-10)]
                    .publicUniqueId
                : intakePageUrl
            "
            target="_blank"
            style="color: #fff; font-size: 0.85rem"
          >
            {{ registeredUserList[item.phoneNumber.slice(-10)].fullname }} ({{
              registeredUserList[item.phoneNumber.slice(-10)].role
            }})
          </el-link>
        </span>
        <span
          v-else
          class="formated-phone-number"
          v-html="formatPhoneNumberWithoutStar(item.phoneNumber)"
        ></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      style="flex: 1; padding: 2px 5px 2px 0"
      class="human-assigned-priority"
      :class="item.boxClassAssignedByTherapist"
    >
      <el-tag
        v-if="item.assignToUser"
        type="primary"
        effect="dark"
        size="small"
        round
        style="float: right; font-size: 0.6rem; height: 18px"
      >
        Assigned to: {{ item.assignToUser.assignedToName }}
      </el-tag>
    </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

I tried to use v-if, or v-show where ever required, used computed property somewhere but no improvement

The sample data is,

```
{
    "data": {
        "1-5698788878": {
            "index": 4,
            "data": [
                {
                    "conversationId": 1,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "Testing content 1",
                    "timestamp": "1688563560000",
                    "sentByName": "user1"
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 1563,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "Testing content 2",
                    "timestamp": "1688563833650",
                    "sentByName": "user2"
                }
            ],
            "assignTo": {
                "assignedToId": 1001,
                "assignedToName": "XYZ",
                "isPinned": false,
                "priority": 1
            },
            "associatedLabels": [],
            "isTakeOver": true,
            "severity": 1
        },
        "2-1209546787": {
            "index": 0,
            "data": [
                {
                    "conversationId": 473,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Hi, This is testing message",
                    "timestamp": "1686146168539",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 474,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "hello",
                    "timestamp": "1686146192998",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 475,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "Hi",
                    "timestamp": "1686308057570",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 476,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "Hello...",
                    "timestamp": "1686830957155",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 477,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "hi",
                    "timestamp": "1686831001292",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 478,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "Hello",
                    "timestamp": "1686837303693",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 479,
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "hello",
                    "timestamp": "1686838923931",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 1063,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Hi",
                    "timestamp": "1687933782142",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 1064,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Hi SRD",
                    "timestamp": "1687933850363",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 1065,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Hello world",
                    "timestamp": "1687933980335",
                    "sentByName": null
                },
                {
                    "conversationId": 1066,
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Hi",
                    "timestamp": "1687934172778",
                    "sentByName": null
                }
            ],
            "assignTo": {
                "assignedToId": 1001,
                "assignedToName": "xyz",
                "isPinned": false,
                "priority": 1
            },
            "associatedLabels": [
                {
                    "label_id": 1,
                    "label_name": "current",
                    "label_type": "primary"
                }
            ],
            "isTakeOver": true,
            "severity": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please clean your HTML and provide only the user list's markup

Comment: I linted the code just to make it more readable, but it's still unlikely to be helpful.  not sure why just the header would be causing a performance issue, but there's too much missing information, not just regarding the header functionality but the rest of the page.  performance issues are hard to debug without having full information.  a runnable example that reproduces the issue would be ideal.

Comment: How did you debug the application? Use [Vue.js dev tools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) to dig deeper which functions are responsible for the performance hit.

Comment: As per your conditional operator code. I have few questions. what is `item` ? from where it comes ? when it gets loaded ?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for responding here.. I'm showing the sample data here, Please check it once..
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.5106968229144ecc8c81670f0676e8a0

I'm working with this kind of records. In real case there is more than 500 objects are there, which is represented as item.

Comment: Please include sample data and such in the question itself instead of linking to it; a question should be self-contained; i.e., it should contain all relevant information in it itself. If there is a lot of it, you can put it in a collapsed Snippet.

Comment: Okay Darryl Noakes